# Inflating a View inside a Layout after adding a MapFragment to the same layout weird behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-fragments

I have the following parent layout for an activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I also have the following layout for a `Fragment` that goes into that `ViewPager`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

At runtime the `FrameLayout` gets populated on the `onCreateView()` method of the Fragment like this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        ViewGroup MapView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frament_mood_map, container, false);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //Adding map fragment to the FrameLayout.
            transaction.add(R.id.mapLayout, mapFragment, "map").commit(); 
        }

        //Adding the mood panel.
        ViewGroup mapLayout = (ViewGroup) MapView.findViewById(R.id.mapLayout);
        mapLayout.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.mood_panel_layout, null));

        ...

        return MapView;
    }
```

The expected behavior is that since the container that gets populated by the `Fragment` and the `View` is a `FrameLayout`, the former gets added first to the container, and then the later would be on top of the map, I want to show a map with a little panel on top which has buttons, I cannot define the `Fragment` inside the XML because (citing the docs, and yes I've tried to do it):

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout
>   includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added
>   to a fragment dynamically

What am I doing wrong? how can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of fiddling and trying to find a workaround I found out that there's a updated `MapView` on Google Maps Android API v2, so for those having the same issue where you need to nest within a `ViewPager` page fragment a `MapFragment` just use the `MapView`.

I found about `MapView` in the following SO question: [Should I use MapView or MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236762/should-i-use-mapview-or-mapfragment)