# Differences between MapView, MapFrament and SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, android-mapview, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I would know the differences because I'm developing an app and I would introduce Google Map API v2 for compiling above Android 2.3.
Which should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236762/should-i-use-mapview-or-mapfragment

Comment: @Viherbar: Please check my answer. If it seems fine and helped to resolve your query then please approve it. Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 19):

**MapView:**

A View which displays a `map` (with data obtained from the Google Maps service). When focused, it will capture `key-presses` and `touch` gestures to move the map.

Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the `Activity` or `Fragment` containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class.

> Use it if you are going to add a `map` into a `fragment`. (you need to
>   update each lifecycle to MapView).

See Google API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)

**MapFragment:**

A `Map` component in an app. This `fragment` is the simplest way to place a `map` in an application. It's a wrapper around a view of a map to automatically handle the necessary life cycle needs.

> Use it if you want to add a `map` into `Activity` class (not fragment
>   because it will create a nested fragment and it´s a mess).

See Google API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment).

**SupportMapFragment:**

A `Map` component in an app. This `fragment` is the simplest way to place a map in an application. It's a wrapper around a view of a `map` to automatically handle the necessary life cycle needs. Being a `fragment`, this component can be added to an `activity's` layout file simply

> Use `SupportMapFragment` if you are targeting Android API levels below 12.

See Google API [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment).

Comment: Use this class only if you are targeting API 12 and _**above**_ 
You wrote below API 12 which is not correct.